# Export/import WLAN profiles in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, wifi, profile

I created a simple script that creates a ps folder on the C drive and saves there the information about the name of the wifi connection and the password from it in xml files. Currently the script looks like this

```
$challenge = Read-Host "Export(1) or Import(2)?"
if ($challenge -eq "1"){
try{
New-Item -Path 'C:\ps\' -ItemType Directory
netsh wlan export profile key=clear folder=c:\ps
}
}elseif ($challenge -eq "2"){
try{
}
```

How can I add the function to export all xml files created on the c drive and then import it on another computer?
I know there is a command netsh wlan add profile netsh wlan add profile filename="c:\ps\Wireless network-Xiaomi_20F5.xml" user=all But this command only works with a specific xml file
The script needs to work on 11 and 10 Windows.

Comment: "But this command only works with a specific xml file" okay, so use `Get-ChildItem` to discover the file names on disk, use `ForEach-Object` to loop through them so you can run the `add profile` command for each.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$challenge = Read-Host "Export(1) or Import(2)?"
if ($challenge -eq "1") {
  New-Item -Path 'C:\ps\' -ItemType Directory

  $ProfileList = Invoke-Expression -Command 'netsh wlan show profile'
  $ProfileList | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $matches = $null
    $null = $PSItem -match ': (?<ProfileName>.*)$'
    if ($matches) {
      netsh wlan export profile $matches.ProfileName key=clear folder=c:\ps
    }
  }
} elseif ($challenge -eq "1") {
  $XmlDirectory = 'c:\ps'
  Get-ChildItem $XmlDirectory | Where-Object {$_.extension -eq '.xml'} | ForEach-Object {
    netsh wlan add profile filename=($XmlDirectory + '\' + $_.name)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this PowerShell script:

```
$folderPath = "C:\ps"
$xmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter *.xml

foreach ($xmlFile in $xmlFiles) {
    $xmlFilePath = $xmlFile.FullName
    netsh wlan add profile filename="$xmlFilePath" user=all
}
```